# ionic 3 angular animation on number counter

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, ionic3

I am showing a number in my UI. nothing hifi just a regular

```
<ion-label>{{myCount}}</ion-label>
```

There is a button next to it called reset. On hitting the button counter becomes 0. This super basic thing and works fine by a function call on button as

```
reset(){
 this.myCount = 0;
}
```

However, for a nicer user experience I want to roll it down to 0 visually reducing 8 to 0. Applying a for loop like

```
  for(let num = currentCount; num >= 0; num --)
       this.myCount = num;
```

probably goes too fast that it doesn't show it happening. any advise to make use of some animation coming from ionic 3 or angular or if none then some other way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use interval:

```
let interval = setInterval(()=>{
  this.myCount--;
  if(this.myCount == 0) clearInterval(interval);
},200)
```